# Can someone help me read this hierarchical regression table?

Tags: regression, multilevel-analysis

What do all the symbols mean?

```
Table 2
Summary of Hierarchical Regression Analysis for Variables Predicting Depression (N=108)
                      Model 1                 Model 2
Variable          B     SE B    β          B    SE B    β
RSES            -.613   .119  -.449     -.600   .120   -.440
UES             -.027   .044  -.055
R2                  .201                    .194
Adjusted R2         .194                    .189 
F                   26.705***               13.473*** 
F change            26.705***                0.395 
*** p<.001
```

Comment: You probably need to show some code and explain the variables a bit if you want to get a good answer.

Comment: Where does this come from? Is it from a book? Package output? Something else?

Comment: Important in the first place is what is hierarhical regression. The term is not uniquely defined. Please give you definition, describe it in few statements.

Comment: hierarhical regression is used to control the effect of some variables. Based on theory variables are entered in specific order and results can be interpreted accordingly. F-change (& it's significance level) shows weather adding more variables contribute to the model significantly or not.